# zxing library doesn't scan small QRCode iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, zxing

I am using zxing library to scan the qrcode, although it will scan the large qrcode but it is failing to scan the small qrcode. Any idea about this?

Comment: How small? What iOS device?

Comment: Are you using it by Intent?

Comment: QR image is 8x8mm(< 1x1 cm), all iOS device especially iPhone4